# Imacro uploading image

Tags: image-uploading, imacros

I am trying to upload an image to URL GOTO=http://www.kijiji.ca/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=696 this website.

```
VERSION BUILD=8340723 RECORDER=CR
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1  
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !DATASOURCE bp.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 6
SET !LOOP 4
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
WAIT SECONDS=5
URL GOTO=http://www.kijiji.ca/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=696
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:PostAdMainForm ATTR=ID:priceAmount CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:PostAdMainForm ATTR=ID:postad-title CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:PostAdMainForm ATTR=ID:forsaleby_s
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:PostAdMainForm ATTR=ID:pstad-descrptn CONTENT={{!COL4}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:PostAdMainForm ATTR=ID:pstad-map-address CONTENT={{!COL5}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:PostAdMainForm ATTR=ID:PhoneNumber CONTENT={{!COL6}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:PostAdMainForm ATTR=ID:YoutubeURL CONTENT=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6dTrQVzgio

TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:PostAdMainForm ATTR=ID:ImageUploadButton
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:PostAdMainForm ATTR=ID:ImageUpload    CONTENT=C:\fakepath\GDT650SGFBB.jpg
WAIT SECONDS=20
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:PostAdMainForm ATTR=NAME:saveAndCheckout
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

When I tried uploading and recording the macro in, it gives me ATTR=ID:html5_fasdfsadfas <- code .

Could you help me out please.

Thank you

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515738/error-sorry-upload-functionality-is-currently-not-supported-in-imacros-for-chr) gives the answer that "**upload functionality is currently not supported in iMacros for Chrome**", so (for example) you may apply successfully this macro in 'iMacros' for Firefox

Comment: What do you mean? I should try with firefox?

Comment: Exactly as you wrote!

Comment: This does not seem to work for `iMacros Firefox` either at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iMacro version 9 is not supporting Upload functionality kindly try to donwload version 8.9.7 of iMacro then your script will work fine there is no any bug in the script.