# Error: Sorry, upload functionality is currently not supported in iMacros for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, imacros

**Error: Sorry, upload functionality is currently not supported in iMacros for Chrome**

--------------------------Code is --------------------------

```
VERSION BUILD=8340723 RECORDER=CR

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ACTION:upload.php ATTR=NAME:uploadFile CONTENT=C:\Dharmendra\Desktop\newfile.csv

WAIT SECONDS=5

ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=downloadnewfile WAIT=YES

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:upload.php ATTR=*
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me. I'm not sure what you're trying to ask.

Comment: is there any other way ?